I want to write a test with pytest for my login view function. The problem is I don't know how to find where my login view redirects
This is my login view.I want to check if I provided the correct credentials. where my view goes
def login_page(request):
    form = LoginForm()
    message = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['username'], password=form.cleaned_data['password'])
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('/')
            else:
                message = 'wrong username or password'
    return render(request, 'AppUser/login.html', context={'form': form, 'message': message})

This is my test. How can I find what the response url is???
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_post_login_view_correct_credentials():
    user = User.objects.create_user("testuser",make_password("password"))
    data = {"username": user.username, "password": user.password}
    client = Client()
    response = client.post(reverse("login_page"), data,follow=True)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assertRedirects(response, reverse("index"))

